# How to start jobs dynamical

Tags: java, sql, java-ee-6

I have an server and a table my current timed Jobs are started in a class where I have different methodes annotated with the @Schedule annotation.

Now I have another form of timed jobs where different requests should be sent to a service in definable time interval. So the user is able to choose something like every 5 minutes or every hour or daily. I will make a list of valid intervals so that there won't be values like every 38 minutes.

So this new timer has to look into the table in whitch interval a job has to be done and then call the function to get the data from the service.
Is this possible without making a new column for something like "Next run"? and what about timers that run at the same time like a 5 Minute a hourly and a dayly timer run all at once once in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a "Next Run" column, I would add a new table that logs when each job was run. That way when your service worker runs it can check the configured run-interval to the last run-time.